# Identity 2.0 Web Api, iOS and Android Clients Facebook app approval always rejected

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-apps, asp.net-identity-2

Here is our setup:

1) a Web Api project with ASP.NET Identity 2.0 with external login support for Facebook.
2)A native iOS App and a native Android App

We are using the appid and secret in the web api and the identity Facebook authorization options. and using web views to do the login process for Facebook.  However, we are also, after the user is authenticated, allowing them to share different pieces of the application to Facebook.  Currently, the website shows the scope of publish_actions, user_videos and user_photos.

Facebook is telling us that custom web views are not okay, and that we have to use the native SDK's on all of them.  What's the purpose of identity providing the ability to utilize getting external accounts and access tokens if you can't even use them on a mobile app?  All of our code that does the sharing process happens on the actual controllers in the web api project. We display a popup that allows the user to enter the text that gets posted, just as Facebook describes.

How can we submit a Facebook App that will explain to them that the website is the actual application that utilizes the Facebook actions we are requesting?

Is this even possible?  if not, why is the technology even available to allow external logins via an api, when you'd most likely be using it to service a native mobile client??

Thanks for the help,
Brent

Comment: You have to use the native SDKs for login on iOS and Android.

Comment: I guess i'm not sure what the difference is between a web view in iOS or android and just linking out to safari on a website and doing the login from there.  It seems silly to require us to use the sdks

Comment: the apps aren't even what's executing the sharing, and we aren't using the sdk's to share either.  We are displaying a modal with a share button, and a text box to type what the user wants. After that the api uses the token that identity gathered during the login, to execute the post to their walls.  So, if the app isn't required to use the sdk's to share, why should the apps be required to use the sdks to login?

Comment: The experience for the user is a million times better if you use the Facebook Native SDKs. And I'm just telling you want the rules say